# Lighting textField

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, textfield

I am making chat app and I want to Light login and password textFields then user do not enter correct data. I want do it with some animation. So is there some libs to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to confirm you want to highlight the a text field when the user enters an invalid value? Sorry to ask but it wasn't totally clear. iOS has some great animation tools that you can use with called to UIView class methods. For example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    [myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

would set the background colour to red over a 0.5 second period.
It all depends on what you want to do.
You can animate changes to the standard properties of a text field (colours, position, frame etc..) easily.
You can do more complex things by dropping down to the textfield layer.
In short the functions you need are part of the SDK.
Here's some links...

[UIView Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html)

[Core Animation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)